# How to pass argument in ctools_modal_form_wrapper?

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

A very strange issue come across while using **ctools_modal_form_wrapper** and **ctools-use-modal**. I have written a menu item and passed two arguments in it.

```
$items['a/b/c/d/e/%/edit/%ctools_js'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'generate_tpls_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(5,7),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'file' => 'tpl_popup_create.inc'
  );
```

Now in this callback I am getting both **5th and 7th argumen**t. But when I pass it to `$form_state`, form is unable to get this 5th argument. I will explain you more with the help of code.

```
function generate_tpls_callback($cid, $ajax) {
    if ($ajax) {
        ctools_include('ajax');
        ctools_include('modal');

        $form_state = array(
            'ajax' => TRUE,
            'title' => t('Display box to change title'),
            'cid' => $cid,
        );
        $output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('myform', $form_state);
        if (!empty($form_state['ajax_commands'])) {
            $output = $form_state['ajax_commands'];
        }
        print ajax_render($output);
        drupal_exit();
    } else {
        print_r("helloooo");
//        
    }

}
```

**So, the issue is**, when I click a link say "**generate tpl**" a popup appears that contains form items. I want the above **5th argument** appears in this form. i.e. `$cid`. How can I do this. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You must use $form_state to do it.

*$form_state['build_info']['args'] = array($node);*

```
function generate_tpls_callback($cid, $ajax) {
    if ($ajax) {
        ctools_include('ajax');
        ctools_include('modal');

        $form_state = array(
            'ajax' => TRUE,
            'title' => t('Display box to change title'),
            'cid' => $cid,
        );
        $form_state['build_info']['args'] = array($myvar);  //Check form below
        $output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('myform', $form_state);
        if (!empty($form_state['ajax_commands'])) {
            $output = $form_state['ajax_commands'];
        }
        print ajax_render($output);
        drupal_exit();
    } else {
    }

}

function myform($form, &$form_state, $myvar) {
...
}
```